# Nhibernate Could not compile the mapping file

Tags: c#, asp.net, nhibernate

my Customer.cfg.xml file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
 <hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" auto-import="true" 
  assembly="OnlineShop" 
   namespace="OnlineShop">
   <class name="Customer" table="Customer" dynamic-update="true" >
    <cache usage="read-write"/>
    <id name="CustomerID" column="CustomerID" type="long">
        <generator class="native" />
    </id>

    <property name="Name"  />
    <property name="Fname" />
    <property name="Phone" />
</class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

my assemly name is WebApplication2,my model is:

```
 public class Customer
{
    public virtual long CustomerID { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual string Fname { get; set; }
    public virtual string Phone { get; set; }
}
```

but i get a error which saying Cant compile Customer.cfg.Xml file

here is my solution screen shot
[image: solution]

Answer (score 0):

I think that's because the closing tab `</hibernate-mapping>` is missing at the end of the file.